# Delete row in a database

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is the Mp_DB class and the method `getMPName()` and `delete()` method are posted. `getMP_Name()` method return string contains the name of the MP.

```
public class MP_DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MP.db";
private static final String MP_TABLE_NAME = "MPData";

MP_DB (Context context) { 
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}// end of 

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + MP_TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            " name TEXT, " +
            " lat REAL, " +
            " lng REAL, " +
            " date TEXT, " +
            " time TEXT " +
            ");" );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public String getMP_Name(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor) db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM MPData WHERE "+
                                                BaseColumns._ID+" = "+
                                                Long.toString(id), null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String r = c.getString(0);
    return r;       
}
```

I get the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbook.MP/com.androidbook.MP.MyLocations}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
at com.androidbook.MP.MP_DB.getMP_Name(MP_DB.java:44)
at com.androidbook.MP.MyLocations.get_MPNames(MyLocations.java:179)
at com.androidbook.MP.MyLocations.onCreate(MyLocations.java:59)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Your delete method seems fine, though I would have done it that way:
`db.delete(MP_TABLE_NAME, BaseColumns._ID+"=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});`

Comment: -1 where is logcat log and table named `MP_TABLE_NAME` definition ... let me guess ... no such column `_id` ...

Comment: which logcat message should I display??? sorry i\m new in that

Comment: @Boris: how to find the stack trace?

Comment: @user1121443 Do you develop in eclipse, intellij idea or command line?

Comment: Window -> Show view -> other -> Android -> Logcat. This is the console that prints out all the logs together with the exception stack traces. Stack traces are visualized in red. Up there you should see your exception when you do the deletion. Select all the exception lines (they will be plenty) and place them here.

Comment: @boris: i posted them..see above

Comment: Your error is in completely different place as the logcat shows. See here: `com.androidbook.MP.MP_DB.getMP_Name(MP_DB.java:44)`. Post the `MP_DB` class. Point us to its 44th line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query doe snot return any results here:

```
SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor) db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM MPData WHERE "+
                                            BaseColumns._ID+" = "+
                                            Long.toString(id), null);
c.moveToFirst();
String r = c.getString(0);
```

Thus the last line throws the error. Please make sure the query should return the expected value.

Also I never query my database with raw query. Try doing it that way:

```
String tableName = "MPData";
String [] columns = { "name" };
String where = BaseColumns._ID + "=?";
String [] whereArgs = { Long.toString(id) };
SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor) db.query(tableName, columns, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
```

Afterwords make the following check to see if the query returned any results:

```
if (c.getCount() > 0) {
    c.moveToFirst();
    r = c.getString(0);
} else {
    // the query returned nothing. Do appropriate action.
}
```

Also never forget to close your databases and cursors (or you will get errors). So the final version of the method:

```
public String getMP_Name(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String tableName = "MPData";
    String [] columns = { "name" };
    String where = BaseColumns._ID + "=?";
    String [] whereArgs = { Long.toString(id) };
    SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor) db.query(tableName, columns, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);

    String r = "";
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        r = c.getString(0);
    } else {
        // the query returned nothing. Do appropriate action.
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return r;       
}
```

PS: Mind my edits of your question. Formatting it that way makes it quite easier for users to read.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier just write a normal SQL statement?

```
String string_id = Long.toString(id);
String sql = "DELETE FROM " + [table_name] + " WHERE " + [primary_key_column] + " = " + string_id;
```

Substituting [table_name] and [primary_key_column] with whatever they are in your case.
Not sure what platform you're working with but there should be some kind of query method you can pass the string to.